# mysql confused with primary / foreign key to achieve given result

Tags: mysql

```
create table users (

    id int,

    username varchar(256) primary key,

    password varchar(256) not null




);


create table grades (
    id int not null auto_increment primary key,    
    username varchar(256) not null,    
    assignmentName varchar(256) not null,    
    mark int,  
    foreign key(username) references users(username)    
);

insert into users values 

(NULL, "a", "x"),
(NULL, "b", "x"),
(NULL, "c", "x");


insert into grades values

(null, "a", "a1", 10),
(null, "a", "a2", 20),
(null, "c", "a1", 30)
```

I want this:

users

```
id   username   password
1    a          x 
2    b          x
3    c          x
```

grades

```
id   username   assignmentname   mark
1    a          a1               10 
1    a          a2               20
3    c          a1               30
```

The grades table's id to user relation is the same with the users table. Without hard coding the values. Is there anyway I can do this? I'm a bit confused if you could even do this with keys.

With the current code they do not have any relation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do two things to resolve the keys on your tables:

1. Table `users`: Use a numeric column for the primary key of table
   `users`. A `VARCHAR` column of length 256 is not a good choice for a
   primary key.
2. Table `grades`: If you have defined the primary key of your `grades`
       table as NOT NULL AUTO INCREMENT, why are you trying to populate this 
       column with NULLs in your SQL. A primary key can never be NULL. So you
       should employ a integer-based column called gradeId or similar for
       this table.

So your tables become:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    userId INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    username VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
    password VARCHAR(256) NOT null
    PRIMARY KEY (userId)
)

CREATE TABLE grades (
    gradeId INT NOT NULL AUTO INCREMENT,    
    userId INT NOT NULL,    
    assignmentName VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,    
    mark INT,  
    PRIMARY KEY (gradeId),
    CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (userid) REFERENCES users (userId) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
)
```

This way, you will have a valid 1:M (one to many) database relationship.

There are two considerations:

1. Entity integrity: To ensure that every row in a table is unique.
   This means that each row is identified by at least one column making
   up a primary key.
2. Referential integrity: This ensures the consistency of foreign keys
   in relationships between tables. Any value of a foreign key in a
   *child* table, must be found in the primary key of a *parent* table. In
   your case, any `user` referred to by the foreign key in
   table `grade` must have a matching primary key in table `user`.

Comment: How would I write the insert though? If userId cannot be null wouldn't I have to hard code values which im trying to avoid.

Comment: When using tables in a relational database, values of primary keys have always got to be specified.

Comment: You cannot define gradeId  as AUTO INCREMENT since he wants both grades for studentA to have id = 1

Comment: The value of a grade is given in column `mark`, not the primary key of table `grades`.

Comment: I see it now. You added a gradeId and userId in table grade.  Adding GradeId is not on his requirement.

Comment: The original SQL will not allow column `id` of table `grades` to store duplicate values because it is a primary key. I have tried to resolved this using a typical 1:M relationship.

Answer (score 0):

You should design the table properly.  Use `INT` for the key.  Also when you insert, always specify column names.  In table definition below, you can link `grades` to `users` by their `userId`.

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    id INT AUTO INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
    , username VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL
    , password VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE grades (
    id INT AUTO INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
    , userId INT NOT NULL
    , assignmentName VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL
    , mark INT
    FOREIGN KEY(userId) REFERENCES users(id)
)

INSERT INTO users(username, password) VALUES('a', 'x')
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some things you need to do in the schema:

1)  You only define auto increment if it is a primary key
2)  You can define username as UNIQUE since id is now primary
3)  You can use a tempGrade table to get user id
4)  Insert into Grade table using the query below

```
insert into grades
select u.id, u.username, t.assignmentName, t.mark 
from tmpgrades t
left join users u
on t.username=u.username;
```

Create Schema:

```
create table users (
    id int not null auto_increment PRIMARY KEY,
    username varchar(256) not null UNIQUE KEY,
    password varchar(256) not null
);

create table tmpgrades (
    id int,    
    username varchar(256) not null,    
    assignmentName varchar(256) not null,
    mark int
);

insert into users values 
(NULL, "a", "x"),
(NULL, "b", "x"),
(NULL, "c", "x");


insert into tmpgrades values
(null, "a", "a1", 10),
(null, "a", "a2", 20),
(null, "c", "a1", 30);

create table grades (
    id int not null,    
    username varchar(256) not null,    
    assignmentName varchar(256) not null,    
    mark int,  
    foreign key(username) references users(username)    
);
```

Query to insert:

```
 insert into grades
    select u.id, u.username, t.assignmentName, t.mark 
    from tmpgrades t
    left join users u
    on t.username=u.username;

select * from grades;
Result:
id  username    assignmentName  mark
 1  a           a1              10
 1  a           a2              20
 3  c           a1              30
```